# How to check if a class file version 50.0 (Java 6) has been preverified?

Tags: java, class, scala, bytecode, verification

I "upgraded" some jar files from class file version 49.0 to 50.0 with ProGuard.

Because preverification is optional with version 50.0, I wonder if there is a way to check if the class file has really an StackMapTable attribute in it.

(It's not that I don't trust ProGuard "[...] The following options upgrade class files to Java 6, by updating their internal version numbers and preverifying them." but I'd like to learn how to verify the existance of the StackMapTable.)

Comment: soo u dont have sources and you couldnt compile it with java 6 compiler???

Comment: I'm using it with Scala and `scalac` only generates code for Java 5 (49.0) at the moment.

Comment: but you shouldnt have problems java 5 compiled code to run in jvm 6

Comment: That's not the point. I want to find out if the signatures and bytecode emitted by `scalac` work with preverification and that was the only way I found except modifying `fjbg` itself.

Comment: Does something like bcel help? http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/StackMap.html

Comment: @philwb: It seems that this only covers the Micro Edition. The SMT on DE is different.

Comment: Not sure about bcel support for stackmap entries actually being restricted to j2me, but, javaassist also has some support for stack map tables that might be useful to you: http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/StackMapTable.html

Comment: philweb: That looks good, though I assumed it was as easy as looking at the bytecode with `javap`. Could you create an answer?

Comment: Ok - answer is there.  The one other nugget I came across was java -XX:-FailOverToOldVerifier -Xverify:all <class> which should only verify if there is SMT information in a 50+ version class file.  However, I haven't tried that and cant even tell you what it might look like on output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Javaasist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/bytecode/StackMapTable.html) has support for reviewing stack map tables.

The one other nugget I came across was java -XX:-FailOverToOldVerifier -Xverify:all  which should only verify if there is SMT information in a 50+ version class file. However, I haven't tried that and cant even tell you what it might look like on output.